# WxPython with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wxpython

I have installed wxPython and Eclipse. Configuration of Pydev is done in Eclipse.

Importing the `wx` package is working, but I am unable to use any of `wx` references.

For example `wx.App()` is throwing the error message "**Undefined variable from import**".

Can any one please help me?
I am new to wxpython and eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding wxPython to the forced builtins? See http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#id1